# Unable to inject object using Autofac

Tags: c#, autofac

I am new to IoC and Autofac. I have created a simple console project to test the technique. When I ran the application I am getting this error: The requested service 'AutoFac.BLL.IEmployeeDetail' has not been registered. The following is my code. This line is throwing the error: build.Register(y => new Employee(y.Resolve()));

```
public class Employee
{
    IEmployeeDetail _employeeDetail;

    public Employee(IEmployeeDetail employeeDetail)
    {
        _employeeDetail = employeeDetail;
    }

    public string GetName()
    {
        return _employeeDetail.Name();
    }
}

public class EmployeeDetail : IEmployeeDetail
{
    public string Name()
    {
        return "John Doe";
    }
}

public interface IEmployeeDetail
{
    string Name();
}

public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var build = new ContainerBuilder();
        build.Register(y => new Employee(y.Resolve<IEmployeeDetail>()));
        var container = build.Build();
        Employee employee = container.Resolve<Employee>();

        Console.WriteLine(employee.GetName());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var build = new ContainerBuilder();
    build.Register<EmployeeDetail>().As<IEmployeeDetail>().InstancePerDepenency();
    build.Register<Employee>().AsSelf().InstancePerDependency();
    var container = build.Build();
    Employee employee = container.Resolve<Employee>();

    Console.WriteLine(employee.GetName());
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Explaination:

You have not only to register types that are dependencies but also the types that use these dependencies. Basicly everything you want to be resolved.